# MVC 3 Crypto Helper -- Will this add extra shield to make the password more secure?

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-3, cryptography, html-helper

A

```
string salt = Crypto.GenerateSalt();
string saltAndPwd = String.Concat(originalPassword, salt);
string hashedPwd = Crypto.HashPassword(saltAndPwd);
```

B

```
string hashedPwd = Crypto.HashPassword(originalPassword);
```

May i know Method A and Method B, which is more secure ? or which is the correct approach ? with reflector, i found this is the hash password method in the core :

```
public static string HashPassword(string password)
{
if (password == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
    }
    return HashWithSalt(password, GenerateSaltInternal(0x10));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the main purpose of using a salt is to defeat rainbow tables, adding additional salt to what `HashPassword` already does doesn't seem like it will gain you much benefit, and only incur additional overhead (as you have to store the salt you generate yourself. `HashPassword` builds it into the returned value). For reference, this is what `HashPassword` does:

> The password hash is generated with the RFC 2898 algorithm using a 128-bit salt, a 256-bit subkey, and 1000 iterations. The format of the generated hash bytestream is {0x00, salt, subkey}, which is base-64 encoded before it is returned.

So, in short, what's in the framework already is good enough for any reasonable definition of good enough.

Comment: so, if i'm using the hash password method, is it mean i no need to store the salt and it will generate the same value when i callback the line of crypto.hashpassword ? (i mean when user login, to getback same value comparison...

Comment: If you look at the section from MSDN I posted, it stores the salt in the returned value. So, all you need to store is what you get back from `HashPassword`, and it'll do the rest when you call `Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword`.

Comment: finally, after self implementation, i understood... verifyhashedpassword is used to detect whether it's the original password, and i no need to store the salt =D just keep the hashed password.. in login form, just use verifyhashedpassword(hashedpassword in database, user login input), if true... that's the password =D